# How to run bcoin on testnet?

Tags: testnet, documentation

In the documentation you can specify a network param, but the default `main` network name isn't the same as bitcoind (`livenet`). What is the name of testnet on bcoin?

EDIT: When going by the documentation and adding `network: testnet` to bcoin.conf, I get the error

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Unknown network.
at Function.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcoin/lib/protocol/network.js:161:3)
at Function.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcoin/lib/protocol/network.js:207:20)
at FullNode.Node (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcoin/lib/node/node.js:43:26)
at new FullNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcoin/lib/node/fullnode.js:46:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcoin/bin/node:12:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

My bcoin.conf file is

```
network: testnet
prefix: ~/.bcoin
prune: true
http-port: 8332
api-key: ******
uri: http://localhost
```

Comment: Are you referring to http://bcoin.io/ ??

Comment: Yep! And alternate to bitcoind

Comment: Just curious what is the advantage of bcoin to bitcoind?

Comment: Very modular, entirely written in node.js, has an extensive api built out so you can easily build on top of a node (previously only possible with bitcore), and has an active team whose focus seems to be making this more developer friendly. For example, I'm building a mobile wallet with bcoin as a local backend (without using the node functionality). You can't do that with bitcoind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be as a result of a previous ChainDB having been initialized at ~/.bcoin/chain.ldb/ . You can find information inside of the debug.log file. e.g.

`[I:2017-07-17T09:11:47Z] (chaindb) Opening ChainDB...
[E:2017-07-17T09:11:47Z] (node) Network mismatch for chain.`

1. create a new location for the chain, e.g. ~/.bcoin/testnet/
2. copy the above config with the updated prefix as per the above
3. execute
   `bcoin --prefix ~/.bcoin/testnet/`

Default prefix is "~/.bcoin/", you can override this by using the prefix cli flag

Comment: To add to this, you can specify a config file with `bcoin --config=~/.bcoin/bcoin.conf` (your config location) or you can set a different config file in the testnet or main folder and bcoin should pick it up

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the [configuration page](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/wiki/Configuration), you set

`network: testnet`

In your bcoin.conf file.

Comment: See the question again, I updated it with an error related to this solution (provided by the documentation)

Comment: Did you add the `network: testnet` to your config file?

Comment: Yes, the error occurs when using that config file. The command I use to specify the conf file is `bcoin -config=~/.bcoin/bcoin.conf`